# File permission problems after file upload

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I have some problems with what I think is a file permission issue.
When I run the code below locally (Windows PC) I have no problems with the code but when I run it on the server (CentOS) it fails on the line with "var img = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(fullPath);".

The file gets uploaded OK but it seems like it fails when trying to read the image into Bitmap. I get no error in the logs from the exception.

To verify I did a test with logging och every line and it fails when reading the uploaded file into Bitmap. The file that it tries to read exists and the path is correct. So I belive it is some sort of permission issue. But I can't understand why, or how to fix it.

```
using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(fullPath))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                    stream.Close();                        
                }


                if (fileExtension.ToLower() != ".png")
                {                                                                                                
                    var img = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(fullPath);
                    img.Save(Path.Combine(pathToSave, fileName + ".png"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);                            
                    img.Dispose();
                    System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Made some googling and it seems like using System.Drawing in Linux is not a good idea. But there is an article where they get it done. For instance https://www.vertexfragment.com/ramblings/system-drawing-net-core-linux/.
I think the point is you need to install some libs:

```
sudo apt-get -f install libgdiplus
```

It's for Ubuntu, try to find the same for Centos

Comment: Thanks! I just realised that I use MagickImage in some other parts of the project so I could use that instead for converting into PNG.

Comment: Sure, another way is using a library:)